# Face Recognition using Eigenfaces and SVM

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, svm, object-recognition

I am new to machine learning. I want to develop a face recognition system using scikit-learn. [This](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/face_recognition.html#example-applications-face-recognition-py) is the example given in the tutorials of scikit-learn.

I am not getting how the input is being provided to the program. How should I load a particular image and make my program run to predict the label for that?

Comment: This is a cross-posting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34835159/562769

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the code that you linked to:

```
# Download the data, if not already on disk and load it as numpy arrays

lfw_people = fetch_lfw_people(min_faces_per_person=70, resize=0.4)
```

[`fetch_lfw-poeple`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_lfw_people.html#sklearn.datasets.fetch_lfw_people) is a routine that loads the data and is detailed [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_lfw_people.html#sklearn.datasets.fetch_lfw_people).

Hope this helps!